# Dishonest approach to multiple testing

Tags: multiple-comparisons, p-hacking

Has the following --dishonest-- approach been discussed somewhere? Has it a name?
I am trying to grasp what intrinsic assumption it violates but I am struggling to find the relevant keywords for the search...

---

Suppose that some experiments produce the following results (p-values):

```
> p = c(0.0019, 0.0298, 0.4262, 0.5719, 0.6528)
> p
[1] 0.0019 0.0298 0.4262 0.5719 0.6528
```

The Benjamini-Hochberg procedure (multiple testing correction) reveals that only the first result constitutes a discovery; the adjusted p-values being

```
> p.adjust(p, method = "BH")
[1] 0.0095 0.0745 0.6528 0.6528 0.6528
```

Frustrated, the experimenter adds 3 experiments he somehow knows are significant:

```
> p = c(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0019, 0.0298, 0.4262, 0.5719, 0.6528)
> p
[1] 0.0001 0.0001 0.0001 0.0019 0.0298 0.4262 0.5719 0.6528
```

And now the second result from the original list constitutes a discovery as well:

```
> p.adjust(p, method = "BH")
[1] 0.0002666667 0.0002666667 0.0002666667 0.0038000000 0.0476800000 0.5682666667 0.6528000000 0.6528000000
```

Comment: As human creativeness is infinite, there is probably infinite flavor of p-hacking scenarios, but I doubt this one has a name.

Comment: ... nevertheless, it's an interesting observation!